# How to find a time between nested Json

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb, subquery

I have created a table called `ticket_manager` with the following structure:

[image]

Each time when the user based QR Code gets scanned it will add a new row (either when it's a check-in it will add a new line to "checkIn with "check_in_$count" or a new line to checkOut with "check_out_$count" -> So for example `"check_in_0 is a pair with "check_out_0"`so..
p1 -> 2:00 - 4:00am; 10:00 - 11:00 am
p2 -> 3:00 - 4:00am;
p3 -> 9:00 - 9:30am

**Now I want to make a MYSQL query to find all people which where at the event between a specific time for example: `03:00:00 am` to `05:00:00 am`.**

**I don't really know the best way to loop through the json's (and pair them together).**
 So far I know :
 `SELECT * FROM "wp_ticket_manager" WHERE "event_logs" BETWEEN '31.07.2021 03:00:00' AND '31.07.2021 05:00:00` 
 to get all queries between normal fields (without pairs and json)
`SELECT * FROM "wp_ticket_manager" WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(event_logs, '$.checkIn.check_in_0') BETWEEN '31.07.2021 03:00:00' AND '31.07.2021 05:00:00'`
to check for a specific field (but didn't worked)
Should I change the table layout to make it in any way easier?

**Sample data:**

mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.18-MariaDB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_manager` (
            `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
            `attendee_name` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL, 
            `event_logs` text,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

```
INSERT INTO `ticket_manager` (id, attendee_name, event_logs)
VALUES (1,'p1','{"checkIn":{"check_in_0":" 31.07.2021 02:00:00 am","check_in_1":" 31.07.2021 10:00:00 am"},"checkOut":{"check_out_0":" 31.07.2021 04:00:00 am","check_out_1":" 31.07.2021 11:00:00 am"}}'), (2,'p2','{"checkIn":{"check_in_0":" 31.07.2021 03:00:00 am",},
"checkOut":{"check_out_0":" 31.07.2021 04:00:00 am"}}'), (3,'p3','{"checkIn":{"check_in_0":" 31.07.2021 9:00:00 am",},
"checkOut":{"check_out_0":" 31.07.2021 9:30:00 am"}}');
```

(Desired output would be all queries between the specfic time in the request)

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data. Also specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: I have added the data. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your data using, for example:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, attendee_name, event_logs, 
                0 level,
                JSON_EXTRACT(event_logs, CONCAT('$.checkIn.check_in_0')) check_in,
                JSON_EXTRACT(event_logs, CONCAT('$.checkOut.check_out_0')) check_out
         FROM ticket_manager
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, attendee_name, event_logs, 
                1 + level,
                JSON_EXTRACT(event_logs, CONCAT('$.checkIn.check_in_', 1 + level)) check_in,
                JSON_EXTRACT(event_logs, CONCAT('$.checkOut.check_out_', 1 + level)) check_out
         FROM cte
         HAVING check_in )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8f0974105b67a2606ea920ea0943c772

Then use extracted `check_in` and `check_out` values (pay attention - their format is not correct DATETIME format for MySQL/MariaDB).